# What is the best companion for getting maximum carrying capacity?

Tags: fallout-4

If I only want to maximize my carrying capacity, what is the best companion to bring assuming I'm willing to take any necessary perks?

I'm not interested in having pocketed or +str equipped items on companions as it gets really messy with the "Take all" action.

Dogmeat works with the Lone Wanderer perk which gives you +100 capacity at rank 2. This already makes dogmeat look like a good candidate for best carrying capacity. However I don't actually know how much each companion is able to carry. In addition the 3rd rank in the Inspirational perk increases carrying capacity, but it doesn't say by how much. If it's an additive bonus this would initially not affect this question, however because Lone Wonderer works with dogmeat I'm unsure if Inspirational also works with dogmeat?

TLDR:

- What is the base carrying capacity (including base strength) for each companion?
- How does the Inspirational perk work, and does it work with dogmeat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character with the most carryweight is Strong who can carry up to 270lbs, which makes him the strongest characters when it comes to carry stuff. No matter if inspirational adds a fix amount or grants a percentage of the carryweight of the companion, strong will always be better.

Unfortunately, I can't say if the Inspirational Perk works with Dogmeat. However, since he doesn't count for the lone wanderer perk, I suppose that the also doesn't count for the Inspirational. However, I'm not sure about that, this is just my first guess. But even if it does, strong will still be able to carry more since he has 270lbs, Dogmeat with lone wanderer only 250lbs (well still 150lbs, but you can carry 100lbs more, which makes 250lbs)

The base carrying capacity is not sure for every character yet, I've taken these from the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_companions):

- Codsworth: 150lbs
- Dogmeat: 150lbs
- Preston Garvey: 165lbs
- Piper: 216.5 lbs
- Strong: 270lbs

Comment: I would keep in consideration the 'wasted' time in trading gear to the companion. Sometimes having the PC carry everything is just  better.

Comment: @DanielZahra That's true, I prefer that too, especially since the trade menu isn't exactly the most comfortable thing to use in the game.

Comment: Try maxing the pack mule perk, as well. It's so good. Going by companions is probably cheaper since if you go pack mule you should probably invest in agility + ap regen, but dang. I love to fast travel back home with 1000lbs of nothing but junk in my backpack.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC Actually if you want to go Strong Back the most important stat will be endurance. It will have many times more impact than just total AP and AP regen. I have a character with 17 endurance, and the difference in run distance is just crazy. I can easily run from bunker hill to goodneighbour, or possibly diamond city just on one single AP bar. And it turned out that the Strong Back perk works the same way, so I can basically just pick up whatever I want and never get encoumbered. I do however lose the ability to run once I'm over my carrying capacity.

Comment: @EJS Damn. I just have 3 legendary AP regen armors and the AP regen perks. Which works great, by the way, but one million endurance sounds more useful. Though, so much ap regen makes battles a breeze with VATS.